# For time series AR model given by (...) Show that equivalent representations are :(...)

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I'm supposed to show that for an AR model given by y(t) = a0 + a1*y(t-1)+ Et
we have equivalent representation in (y(t)-average(y)) = a1(y(t-1)-average(y))

where average(y) is the unconditional mean of the y(t) series

I have no idea how to even start? Up until now I've just been solving some normal time series with homogenous and particular solution.

Comment: You need to add the self-study tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hi: calculate the unconditional ,mean an then plug that into your
 $y_t - average(y) = a1 y_{t-1} - average(y)$ formula. Then show that the equation you have is algebraically equivalent to the original AR(1) with intercept.  For calculating the unconditional mean, take the expectation of both sides of the AR(1) with intercept and then solve for the expected value of $Y_t$. (Use the fact that the expectation of $Y_t$ is constant for all $t$.)  The expected value of $Y_{t}$ is what is meant by the unconditional mean. I would get also get my hands on a  good intro time series book. There's a green one by Chatfield that's fairly recent and not bad. An older one that is often recommended is the Box-Jenkins-Reinsel text.  There's also a  another green one by Ledolter. Personally, I don't recommend Box-Jenkins-Reinsel as a useful text when starting out. There are better intro books. I just can't think of any recent ones besides Chatfield.